# Restrict values set to the property

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I am creating a compiler. I have following `Token` definition:

```
public sealed class Token
    {
        public TokenType Type { get; private set; }
        public string Lexeme { get; private set; }
        public int CurrentLine { get; private set; }

        public Token(TokenType type, string lexeme, int currentLine)
        {
            Type = type;
            Lexeme = lexeme;
            CurrentLine = currentLine;
        }
    }
```

The `TokenType` is an enum in which I have different token types.

```
public enum TokenType
    {

        // keyword
        PrintKeyword,
        VarKeyword,
        //...

        // literal
        IntegerLiteral,
        //...

        // identifier
        Identifier,

        //...
    }
```

The tokenizer gives the parser the stream of tokens, and then the parser starts to generate an abstract syntax tree. In my implementation I have one class for each node type.

```
class Operand
    {
        Token token { get; set; }
            //Token.Type
                //IntegerLiteral || Identifier

    }

    class Term
    {
        Token termOperator { get; set; }
            //Token.Type
                //Multiplication || Division
        Operand termOperand1 { get; set; }
        Operand termOperand2 { get; set; }

    }

    //...
```

As you see, one of the class is `Operand` which stores Token given by parser. How can I secure it, so that `<OperandObjHere>.token` accepts only `IntegerLiteral` or `Identifier`? Is checking it in a set method the only way, and then throwing an exception if it does not match the rule? Is it the best practice for it? I would like to also know if creating separate class for each node type is the way to go?

Comment: I feel that something is wrong with arch. Probably you need to make your code more polymorphic. Because it looks strange when you try to filter unacceptable values.

Comment: The parser would never create a bad Term anyway, since it creates one only after finding one of the tokens that is supposed to result in a Term.

Comment: The question is very broad, especially without a good [mcve] showing why this is even something worth solving (see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45775416/restrict-values-set-to-the-property#comment78509140_45775416)). I also agree that if it _does_ need solving, a polymorphic approach would be better, where the `Token` property is a virtual member of a base type (e.g. "node"), and each subclass can apply its own restrictions. Implemented either in the setter, or via some explicit filtering mechanism (e.g. a protected collection of valid values).

Comment: How about not storing `Token` in the nodes at all and storing only required information from the given token?

Answer (score 1):

You could just check it in the `set` of the `Token` property. Uses C#7 syntax.

```
class Operand {

    private Token token;

    Token Token {
        get => token;
        set => token = (value.Equals(TokenType.IntegerLiteral) || value.Equals(TokenType.Identifier)) ? value : throw new Exception("Token must be IntegerLiteral or Identifier");
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said I am looking for an alternative: "Is checking it in a set method the only way, and then throwing an exception if it does not match the rule?". Also is creating separate classes for each node type the way to go?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do it this way? What is the expected behavior for an invalid value? As far as I know, you can't restrict `enums` at compile time. You could use another `enum` that only has the valid values but there would still need to be some check or conversion.

Comment: It is not really needed, but I think it would be better to prevent from assigning bad tokens, for the future development.